# SQL Query :How do I Utilize Timestamp column among rank Column values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, analytic-functions

We are trying to rank Invoice column and Only want first shipment Invoices among parts of Invoices.

That is in that, column we have multiple Invoices. We would like to select that group of invoices among rank column which consist of Earliest Timestamp.

**Nature of TimeStamp Column:**

The SQL Server timestamp data type has nothing to do with times or dates it is just a binary number to indicate a sequence.The timestamp column is recorded and incremented each time a record is added.

We tried following query :

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         myrank = rank() over (partition by a.SalesOrder order by c.Invoice), 
         c.Invoice, c.TimeStamp
     from 
         OrderDetail a 
     left join 
         OrderMaster b on a.SalesOrder = b.SalesOrder  
     left join 
         InvoiceDetail c on a.SalesOrder = c.SalesOrder 
                         and a.SalesOrderLine = c.SalesOrderLine 
     where  
         a.SalesOrder = '218438'  
         and c.LineType = '1' 
         and b.OrderStatus = '9' ) z
```

**Sample Data:**

```
myrank | SalesOrder | SalesOrderLine |Invoice | TimeStamp
1   218438  8   207964  0x0000000048CD8CD4
2   218438  1   207965  0x0000000048CD8CD5
2   218438  2   207965  0x0000000048CD8CD6
2   218438  3   207965  0x0000000048CD8CD7
2   218438  4   207965  0x0000000048CD8CD8
2   218438  5   207965  0x0000000048CD8CD9
2   218438  6   207965  0x0000000048CD8CDA
2   218438  7   207965  0x0000000048CD8CDB
```

**Expected Data:**

Record Should be rank as First shipment invoice and First Added Record on the basis of timestamp
What  should be the output If i select 2 as my rank

```
myrank | SalesOrder | SalesOrderLine |Invoice | TimeStamp
    1   218438  8   207964  0x0000000048CD8CD4
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How about the table definition as a starting point? As it is we are guessing as to what you are trying to do here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Actually the `timestamp` data type is also altered each time you update a record. Its meant as a solution for concurrency by versioning the record. When 2 processes try to alter the same record one of them will lose out because their `timestamp` no longer matches the one on the record.

Comment: `The timestamp column is recorded and incremented each time a record is added` - if this is something you are looking for so you can identify the first record added in a sequence you should add an `identity` column and not a `timestamp` column. This would be sql server incremented for each new record and then the value would not be changed.

Comment: We would like to rank among Invoice column value .  among this ranking  want to check  which record is added first that would be our First shipment for invoices.

Comment: I have edited the Question. In that , Included Sample data,Expected Data .

Comment: You should forget trying to use the timestamp column in order to determine which row is newest. That isn't how that datatype works at all. Timestamp works on a SINGLE row, not across multiple rows.

Comment: Ok. So  How do i identify among invoices which invoice used at first shipment.

Comment: I would recommend switching your timestamp to a datetime instead. That will allow to order rows by the value in the column across rows.

Comment: Given the data you posted as a sample you have nothing you can use to determine order. You need something on each row that you can use to order.

Comment: my datetime columns are same for each row  that is InvoiceDate
=2016-06-08 00:00:00.000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115242/discussion-between-vickps-and-sean-lange).

Answer (score 0):

Use [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

I don't know your exact table structure but it would be similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT c.Invoice, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.Invoice ORDER BY c.TimeStamp ASC) n
    FROM InvoiceDetails c
    ) i
WHERE i.n = 1
```

Comment: when i am using  your query . getting  this as result http://paste.ofcode.org/cKzb6WH3wB2AnMbDjVCYyv

Comment: It also tells me for two multiple invoices i am could not able to rank for first  Created INVOICE.

Comment: My Intention is with the help of TimeStamp column . can i get it Earliest Invoice among group of  Invoices

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/d9XdFcTtRM5HfkSMArjvEQ I MIXED both of us query.but still not logically convinved .